# Add a Value to Embedded Object

Tags: jquery

I have an array of object:

```
var data = [
    { "name": " Step A ","values": [{"id": "b0", "from": "/Date(1320182000000)/", "to": "/Date(1325573274000)/", "desc": "Id: 0", "label": " Step A1", "customClass": "ganttRed", "dep": "b1"}]},
    { "name": " Step B ","values": [{"id": "b1", "from": "/Date(11/07/2011   )/", "to": "/Date(11/11/2011   )/", "desc": "Id: 1", "label": " Step B1", "customClass": "ganttOrange", "dep": "b2"}]},
    { "name": " Step C ","values": [{"id": "b2", "from": "/Date(1321192000000)/", "to": "/Date(1321500400000)/", "desc": "Id: 2", "label": " Step C1", "customClass": "ganttGreen", "dep": "b3"}]},
    { "name": " Step J ","values": [{"id": "b9", "from": "/Date(1320802400000)/", "to": "/Date(1321994800000)/", "desc": "Id: 9", "label": " Step J1", "customClass": "ganttOrange"}]}
    ];
```

I need to add other items to the element "values". An example of the result should be like this:

```
{ "name": " Step A ","values": [{"id": "b0", "from": "/Date(1320182000000)/", "to": "/Date(1325573274000)/", "desc": "Id: 0", "label": " Step A1", "customClass": "ganttRed", "dep": "b1"}, {"id": "b9", "from": "/Date(1320802400000)/", "to": "/Date(1321994800000)/", "desc": "Id: 9", "label": " Step J1", "customClass": "ganttOrange"}]},
```

I've tried to use this but it's not working.

```
data[values].push({"from": "artDate", "to": "EndDate", "id": "ganttOrange"});
```

Please help.

Comment: There is an index missing. I think you want to add an object in the values property of another object right ?

Comment: Still did not work when I enclosed values with "" like data["values"].push

Comment: @ Béranger Yes I need to add on an object item value inside "value" but not specifically values from other object.

Comment: You can take a look at my answer or Rory's one

Comment: Thanks  Béranger and Rory. Great help! :)

Comment: Another question, Béranger if you may. How I can add the value to the last item in the variable data?

for example, In the below, I'd like to push these values to the last item in data. How would I do that?

data[index].values.push({"from": "artDate", "to": "EndDate", "id": "ganttOrange"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
data[index].values.push({"from": "artDate", "to": "EndDate", "id": "ganttOrange"});
```

Comment: Thanks Béranger. Great help! :)

Comment: Another question, Béranger if you may. How I can add the value to the last item in the variable data? for example, In the below, I'd like to push these values to the last item in data. How would I do that? data[index].values.push({"from": "artDate", "to": "EndDate", "id": "ganttOrange"});

Comment: `data[data.length-1].values.push(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. Firstly, you need to wrap the `values` in quotes so that it's taken as a string literal. Without the quotes JS will assume you mean a variable named `values` which doesn't exist and will cause an error. Alternatively you can use dot notation, i.e. `object.propertyname.push()`.

Secondly, you need to access the `data` array by an index to know which object contains the `values` array to `push()` to. To push to the first object in the array, use `data[0]`, like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "name": " Step A ",
    "values": [{
      "id": "b0",
      "from": "/Date(1320182000000)/",
      "to": "/Date(1325573274000)/",
      "desc": "Id: 0",
      "label": " Step A1",
      "customClass": "ganttRed",
      "dep": "b1"
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": " Step B ",
    "values": [{
      "id": "b1",
      "from": "/Date(11/07/2011   )/",
      "to": "/Date(11/11/2011   )/",
      "desc": "Id: 1",
      "label": " Step B1",
      "customClass": "ganttOrange",
      "dep": "b2"
    }]
  }
];

data[0].values.push({
  "from": "artDate",
  "to": "EndDate",
  "id": "ganttOrange"
});

console.log(data);
```